# Setting up workspace

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently had to reinstall ros and roll back to electric.
I have been trying to configure my system to use my ~/ros_workspace folder instead of the default /opt/ros/electric/
I've tried altering the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and still cannot get ros to recognize that folder.
roscd continues to take me to opt/ros/electric and will not locate my packages even when I explicitly call them.
I've tried following all the instructions I could find in the tutorials and here in the forums, but I'm at a bit of a loss.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39404/setting-up-workspace/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, switching a workspace from fuerte back to electric can always cause errors when compiling / building sources. Be aware of that. It is safer to create separate workspaces for different ROS versions.

Next, I suggest that you use rosws / rosinstall to create and manage your workspaces.

Third, open your .bashrc in some editor, and find any place mentioning ROS_ROOT, ROS_WORKSPACE, or setup.sh.

Delete all those lines. Regarding ROS, there should only be one line in your .bashrc, that reads:

```
source ~/ros_workspace/setup.sh
```

Even if it can work, managing the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH yourself almost always leads to bad ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in the long run and confusing errors.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6